# Utilising the beatIndex method of the SuperPoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer

Tags: android, c++, ios, audio

Thanks in advance for any insight.
I'm trying to use the beatIndex method to sync an effect enable to a beat using the SuperPowered SDK. I've tried casting to int and comparing to the last beat value and triggering on the change but I think the polling is too slow to really work (also have sneaking suspicion that I'm being horrendously inefficient). Are there any SuperPowered users out there with a good way of implementing this? Essentially an "onBeat" event is what I'm looking for.

Thanks and Regards,

Garry